# Soft keyboard does not appear onTouch custom EditText in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a complicated custom view that is very similar to `pinterest` search box. This component simply displays `EditText` and multiple `Button`s in a `LinearLayout`.

*The component works fine with the same layout file when it is in any `Fragment` layout. which means when the user click on it, the `soft-keyboard` displays and works fine with the `EditText`
**BUT**, when I try to add this component to my custom `actionbar`*, it does not work. Which means, clicking on it does not show the `soft-keyboard`.

I believe that this is a focus problem, but I tried to debug and the `EditText` onTouch method is being called normally. I have also tried to work around with the `descendantFocusability` parameter without any result.

Here is my Custom `ActionBar` initialization

```
public void initializeCustomActionBar() {
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mActionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

    View customView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(customView);
}
```

and here is my custom `ActionBar` layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.my.package.customSearch
    android:id="@+id/pdt_actionbar_searchbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

I'm building this custom layout programmatically without XML files. For some reasons I will not be able to post my code to build this layout, but I draw an image explains the hierarchy of the layout of the `ActionBar` in deep details.

NOTE: I'm using `NavigationDrawer` left menu. I think there is a conflict in the focus between it's left menu `Button` and my `EditText`

[image]

Comment: I'm curious about this... Did you solve it?

Comment: @joaquin unfortunately no. I have changed the implementation way by adding custom actionbar with only `EditText` then passing the value from it to another screen with my component

Answer (score 0):

In which activity that Edit Text is there that activity class declare in manifest file there you need to add this line of code below as shown

inside activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"

Comment: This will display the `SoftInput` always without connecting it to the `EditText`. This is not what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this line when to the action bar button listener

your_view.getWindow().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

Comment: Do you mean in it's `OnClick` or `OnTouch` ?

Comment: OnClick is a sort of `OnTouch`, so I suggest `OnClick`

Comment: What do u mean by `your_view` the actionbar or the EditText?

Comment: The actionbar. In fact, i'd add that line I said as a last code for the `initializeCustomActionBar()` method

Comment: I know that line does the magic. Maybe you should detect when the `EditText` is focused and when it does, run that line.

Comment: There is no magic here. Simply this line would work any any different layout except the custom `ActionBar` also I need to connect the EditText with the softkey to be able to type

Comment: I use this on an AlertDialog that has an EditText inside and I do this: `AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);`. That opens the keyboard and like Android already put the cursor on the EditText then it will write there

Comment: Yeah, but instead of the dialog.getWindow what should I do?

Comment: Im sorry for my absence. I'm at work. I think that you don't need to connect your EditText to the softkey. In fact, the keyboard will write where the cursor is placed in. So, only things you need to do is make sure the EditText has focus and then launch this `getWindow().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)`. This will show the keyboard and if you type it will write where the cursor is. Nothing else. Notice i'm calling getWindow() directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the following code after setting your custom search View. searchView should be initialized to the android.widget.searchview .

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
           if (hasFocus) {
               getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
           }
     }
}
searchView.requestFocus();
```

For EditText use setOnFocusChangeListener or android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"